# autoscroll angularjs doesn't seem to work

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat

Hi I'm building a chatapp in angularjs and I want the chatbox to scroll down automatically.  I'm using this example that I put in a directive: http://jsfiddle.net/atRkJ/

It works as it is but when I use it with a ng-repeat it doesn't work.

html file

```
     <ul  id="chat" style="height:300px; overflow:auto" scroll-if>

            <li data-ng-repeat="messageinfo in messages" > 

                <div class="message-date">
                    {{messageinfo[0]}}
                </div>

            </li>

        </ul>
```

directive.js

```
  .directive('scrollIf', function() {
return{
    restrict: "A",
    link: function(scope, element, attributes) {
        var chat_height = $('#chat').outerHeight();
        console.log(chat_height);
        $('#chat').scrollTop(chat_height);
    }
   }
  });
```

Any help? Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you call the code:

```
var chat_height = $('#chat').outerHeight();
console.log(chat_height);
$('#chat').scrollTop(chat_height);
```

Your ***ng-repeat does not run and finish*** its rendering yet => the `outerHeight` returned is not correct.

You must run your code when the `ng-repeat` finishes. To do it, you could define another directive:

```
.directive('scrollItem',function(){
    return{
    restrict: "A",
    link: function(scope, element, attributes) {
        if (scope.$last){ // If this is the last item, trigger an event
           scope.$emit("Finished");
       }
    }
   }
});
```

Use it:

```
<li data-ng-repeat="messageinfo in messages" scroll-item>
```

Your `scrollIf` directive can now be notified when the `ng-repeat` completes

```
.directive('scrollIf', function() {
return{
    restrict: "A",
    link: function(scope, element, attributes) {
        scope.$on("Finished",function(){ //Handle an event when all the items are rendered with ng-repeat
            var chat_height = element.outerHeight();
            console.log(chat_height);
            element.scrollTop(chat_height); 
        });
    }
   }
  });
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/atRkJ/1/)